# How to overlap image half way with container like example shown

Tags: html, css, bulma

I'm trying to create this view but I'm not sure how to get the image to overlap half way with the black background. I've got an svg with the full wide graphic of the car and line where the line breaks in color.

I'm using Bulma as a framework. How would I get the image to overlap a black container as well as the white container?

[image]

[image]

Here's an example of what I've got now: https://codesandbox.io/s/bulma-autocomplete-forked-kdu4h?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Please show us the HTML and CSS you have so far - and include the actual image as that is what needs positioning accurately.

Comment: Just added a link to an example of what I've got

Comment: Are you looking for CSS blend? https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/

Comment: @Nitin I'm just looking for something that works and I can also make mobile responsive

Comment: Oh okay, you can `position:absolute` the image and move it to align it with the container. Remember to add a parent `position:relative` as a wrapper so that the image does not move based on the browser's resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the img responsive you want it to keep its aspect ratio while filling the same width as the black element but you want it to be translated up enough that the break between the white and the black line always stays at the top of the container.

This snippet does that by having the img as a child of the black element and the same width as it but translated upwards by just the right % of its height that the black line starts just above the black element. This is almost at 50% of its height, actually just very slightly more.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 40%; /* just for this demo */
  background-color: black;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transform: translateY(-52.5%);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhA4r.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've got one more similar question, would you mind checking it out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68979000/how-would-i-duplicate-the-placement-in-this-image/68979116#68979116

Answer (score 1):

You could have a svg wave with 2 colors like so

```css
body {
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<svg id="wave" width="740" height="110" viewBox="0 0 740 110" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M1 61.4997C243.5 -30.5003 306.5 2.9997 367 48.9997C427.5 94.9997 592.5 142.999 737 61.4997" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"/>
  <path d="M1 63.6579C244.159 -28.917 307.33 4.79235 367.995 51.0798C428.659 97.3672 594.107 145.667 739 63.6579" stroke="white" stroke-width="3"/>
</svg>
```

---

Then put that down of you top container

```css
.block {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}

#wave {
  float:left;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="block black"></div>
  <svg id="wave" viewBox="0 0 740 110" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M1 61.4997C243.5 -30.5003 306.5 2.9997 367 48.9997C427.5 94.9997 592.5 142.999 737 61.4997" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"/>
    <path d="M1 63.6579C244.159 -28.917 307.33 4.79235 367.995 51.0798C428.659 97.3672 594.107 145.667 739 63.6579" stroke="white" stroke-width="3"/>
  </svg>
<div class="block white"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this... maybe I didn't explain it well. The image I've got already has the difference in colors in the line. What I'm trying to do is have the image overlap on both a white and black background. I've got the first section with the white background and the next section with black background. I'm trying to place the image inbetween both of those.

Comment: Oh, ok so your problem is placing the image and not having the proper image, am I right ?

Comment: Correct. I've created an example of what I've got now: https://codesandbox.io/s/bulma-autocomplete-forked-kdu4h?file=/src/index.js